# What does "you're the one" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Daughter brought her boyfriend Mick to home, so her father & Mick
started conversation.

> Mick: I know. You were in music band, right?
>
> Father: You're impressing me already.
>
> Mick: Well, I have your CDs.
>
> Father: **You're the one**.

My Understanding: Still no one buy his CD's by saying **one** refers Mick is the **first one** to buy CD. since **s** word added to CD, that is why I am confused.

Comment: We would have to have seen the film _If I Stay (2014)_ to say with certainty what the line "You're the one" means here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Indeed, though we can narrow it down with pretty good certainty to either (1) "You're the one for my daughter" or (2) "You're the one who's been buying my CDs" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that Mick is the one who bought the CDs and that this is somehow noteworthy in the mind of the father. However, often when someone is "the one", that person is the most suitable, the best candidate, for something.

In particular, in a romantic context, "the one" is a true love, the person that someone is going to marry. Here, the father is impressed by Mick, so he thinks that Mick is "the one" for his daughter, the person she should marry. Keep in mind that he's joking or being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

The way the conversation is written is a bit confusing, but in the last sentence the Father is saying that Mick is "the one" for his daughter: a slang/casual term meaning that someone is the best and only person that someone else should marry.

You can understand this because Father says that Mick is impressing him after  Mick says that Father was in a band, since this means that Mick knows something that most people do not know (if most people knew that Father was in a band, it would not be impressive if someone said so). When Mick says "I have your CDs", Father becomes really pleased since Mick is saying that he liked Father's music enough to pay for it, when most people don't even know that Father was in a band. This leads Father to say that Mick is "the one" for Daughter.